# So in the decentralized future, we will pay to use services like Twitter, etc.?

Tags: contract-development

I'm currently learning a lot about blockchain and the vision behind smart contracts.

As I understood, the idea of a turning-complete blockchain enables applications like social media platforms, messengers, or something like Google to be decentralized.

To query data, we look up the blockchain. To mutate data/ to mutate the blockchain, we need to send a transaction. This will include every time I want to post or like something on social media, as an example.

So the future of the internet we are looking at, is an ad-free internet, but an internet where people have to pay to participate in it?

Thank you in advance for your answers. I'm very much looking forward to it!

I know this is a fairly conceptual question, but the ethereum subreddit would not let me post under 20 karma points and literally cannot find any other active platform for asking this questions I'm really curious about!

Comment: You can also think it the other way. You don't have much control over your social content, platforms usually monetize the content and you might get a percentage under certain conditions like page views or subscriptions. You also have agreed to the term of use, they can ban you at their sole discretion without giving you any notice. It is also possible to have free platforms with publicity to engage users.